# Passing unique column names to a function

Tags: r, function, loops, arguments

I'd like to pass the names of columns in a data frame to a for loop to populate a matrix.

Here is the function:

```
function.ami<-function(AMI){
  ma<<-as.matrix(subset(dft, ami == as.character(AMI)))
  ma[ma==" "]<<-0
  ma<<-matrix(as.numeric(ma),ncol=ncol(dft))
  return(colMeans(ma[,-(1:6)],na.rm=TRUE))  
}
```

Here is the way I'm calling it:

```
z<-matrix(rep(0,length(unique(dft$ami))*(ncol(dft)-6)),nrow=length(unique(dft$ami)), byrow=TRUE)

for (j in 1:length(unique(dft$ami))){
  z[j,]<-function.ami(unique(dft$ami[j]))
}
```

here is a very clumsy way to generate some sample data:

```
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(ami = c("Trilliant","SSN","GPRS","LNNA","SynchTec"),tr.1 = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 2, replace = TRUE)),tr.2 = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 2, replace = TRUE)),tr.3 = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 2, replace = TRUE)),tr.4 = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 2, replace = TRUE)),tr.5 = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 2, replace = TRUE))))
```

However, when I run this, the `function.ami(unique(dft$ami[j]))` simply returns the same value, no matter what `j` is.

Does anyone have a way to do this?  I'm also open to ideas on how to more eloquently do what this code does other than the clunky for-loop method...or how to generate the sample data frame!

Comment: I suggest you make your example reproducible.

Comment: reproducible data set has been added to the original post via edit.

Comment: @user3033594 can you actually explain what you are trying to do? It seems like you're attempting some sort of split-apply-combine on the unique values of the `ami` variable, since the first thing you do in `function.ami` is to subset your data frame. There is almost certainly a much cleaner, simpler way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have raw data similar to the sample data I have listed.  As you can see, that data can be subsetted into smaller groups based on if they have the same "ami" row name.  I want to get a vector that shows the average of the columns of each of the 5 possible subsets of data (based on ami name) and use that to construct a 6x5 table, with ami names on the rows and mean(tr.x) along the columns.